# AngularJS dynamic application with or without routing

Tags: dynamic, angularjs, routes

My application has 2 purposes:

- It needs to run stand-alone, where it needs routing for choosing a
  study etc.
- Or, it runs integrated in an other project, and only needs
  one controller and one view.

Currently i have a routeProvider configured for the stand-alone application, injecting the pages in the ng-view tag in the HTML.

Now is my question: How can i inject an controller and view in the ng-view (For the integration). I cannot manipulate the HTML since it is static. I cant use a single routeProvider rule, because this can interfeir the application that integrates mine (Other plugins can use the #/.. for info or other things).

Comment: just don't use `.otherwise`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation you can't use routeProvider when other stuff interferes.
Of Course you could prevent routeProvider to act on outside changes of the hashbang with workarounds but thats not nice.
routeProvider will listen to all changes of the url after the hashbang.
So what you should do is to manually bootstrap() your angular app with the controllers you need. If your app is small enough you could even use directives to achieve lazy loading of templates with the attribute templateUrl : "/myurl"

Usually to create a dynamic App use Routing. Simnple point.
The best way to use Angular if you want to unleash all its might don't integrate it.
I explain why:
+ Your state never gets lost due to page reloads 
+ You have full control of the environment and don't have to worry about interfering scripts etc.
+ If your user should manually reload, you can redirect to home/login or even better use requireJS or HTML5 local storage to recover your scopes after a reload

Cheers, Heinrich